# Issue with displaying TabHost Layout in new Intent

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent, android-tabhost

I am having an issue with using TabHost in a new Intent of type TabActivity which I hope you can point me in the right direction. Funnily it works fine when I try to view it in the original Intent : setContentView(R.layout.main)

I get a "forced closed" and within logcat, I get the following error even though my Tabhost id = "@android:id/tabhost":

> 02-18 22:23:11.937:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5944): Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your
>   content must have a TabHost whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

I have declared the second intent in the Manifest.xml file: 
XML:

```
<activity android:name=".NextActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Within the first activity (MainActivity), I start the second intent (NextActivity), with extras, as follows:

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class); 
Bundle b_next=new Bundle(); 

b_next.putString("s_string", myString); 

nextActivity.putExtras(b_next);
```

In my NextActivity.java file, I get the extras and try to display the TabHost View:

```
public class NextActivity extends TabActivity { 
     @Override 
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        String myString; 
        Bundle b_initial; 

        b_initial = getIntent().getExtras(); 

        myString = b_initial.getString("s_string"); 

     setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        } 
}
```

I get the same error with using the TabHost example on the Android Developer site (Hellow View):

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview1" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is a tab" /> 
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview2" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is another tab" /> 
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview3" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:text="this is a third tab" /> 
        </FrameLayout> 
    </LinearLayout> 
</TabHost>
```

Thanks in advance folks...

CLARIFICATION:
This is what I really get from LogCat:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java    285)
>        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java  640)
>        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java  640)
>        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java  640)
>        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java 1645)
>        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java   99)
>        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java    123)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java   3948)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java   521)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java    782)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java   540)
>        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

Comment: I don't see any reference to `TabHost.addTab`; although it doesn't seem like that alone would cause the error, the lack of that code is suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have previously constructed tabhosts with an id of `android:id="@+id/tabhost"`. Does this work for you?

You could also consider constructing your tab view programmatically:

```
    TabHost t = getTabHost();
    TabSpec tab = t.newTabSpec(label)
                   .setIndicator(label, icon)
                   .setContent(intent);
    t.addTab(tab);
```

Comment: Hello Jack, I will try adding the id you suggested and then use findViewById.


However, there was a mistake in my post earlier on. This is what I actually get from LogCat at setContentView in the new intent:

 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java
.....

Comment: Hi Faisal: I'm not sure if this applies to your situation but in some instances TabHost.setup() must be called before adding any tabs. See http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setup%28%29 . It might be worth exploring

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. Luckily there was a quick fix:

1. Delete the `R` file.
2. Wait for your IDE to generate the file.
3. Profit!

Comment: Does anyone know the reason why this works? It worked for me btw. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had copied and pasted code and noticed that in the id attribute I had:

```
android:id="@+id/tabs"
```

when what I really wanted was:

```
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
```

Comment: Aha!  This did it for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem. I had an XML file that wasn't linked against my code properly in my res/layout. When I fixed the naming, the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

even though i had changed my main.xml to use `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"` like the error stated, it kept trying to use the old name.  finally i found the file res/layout-port/main.xml that was identical to main.xml except used the wrong android:id.  i must have added a portrait view accidentally and it was holding on to the old value.  either fixing the portrait file or removing it fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error.  For me it would appear after obfuscation(via ProGuard), pre obfuscation it was fine.

In the end I renamed my layout file to something more complex and unique, and ProGuard didn't mess up the linking. Bit easer than going down the ProGuard configeration path.

So my issue was similar to SapphireSun, though expressed via a different process(and post eclipse, just to make things that bit more difficult).

This is perhaps one of the more obscure ways to get this error, but I thought it worth a mention.

Answer (score 1):

`"public class NextActivity extends TabActivity"` --change TabActivity to  ActivityGroup.

when problem happen when you want wo run tabhost in  tabhost.it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same error in a team-project, when using SVN. Sometimes, eclipse uploads classes.dex and resources.ap_ from the bin folder of the project and others get it via SVN update.

Since these binary files are generated on the individual machines with individual code, thats probably where the error comes from.

Cleaning the project files (Project -> Clean) always solved the issue for us!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue along with 'ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch''. If you updated ADT plug-in in Eclipse but have not updated the SDK at the same time. Updating the SDK Manager in Eclipse, fixed the issue for me.