# App Crashes Only When in Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

My app crashes when I try to launch a new activity. The stack trace does not show anything from my code. I have tested it in both the 1.6 emulator and the 2.1 emulator and it crashes in both situations however it runs on a 2.2 device. Does anyone know what could make the emulator crash like this?

**Stacktrace**

```
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.widget.TabHost.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(TabHost.java:292)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:659)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:659)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:659)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1782)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
01-13 16:18:33.232: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 16:18:33.242: I/dalvikvm(284): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
01-13 16:18:33.422: I/dalvikvm(284): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Do you have nested activities inside Tabhost? Please post your code.

Comment: What code should I post? The activity that deals with the tabhost?

Comment: Try stepping through the code with a debugger to find the line that makes it crash.

Comment: @ethan when i step through the code the app works. I think it might have to do with an asynctask

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295352/issue-with-displaying-tabhost-layout-in-new-intent

Comment: Try it on a 1.6 or 2.1 device or a 2.2 emulator. Might be something that's fixed in 2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled the Android SDK and everything seems to be fine. Very weird!

Comment: please look at my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029404/getting-nullpointerexception-in-my-custom-android-camera-application/14029430

do you think I should do what you did?